# Upload dataframe once and use it everywhere in a shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

In Shiny,we upload the data in the server wrapped in a reactive braces. The file is read through read_csv(). Now, when we use want to use this dataframe for different tasks, we call this reactive function which reads in the dataframe. This seems inefficient. Is there a way to simply read the dataframe once and use it throughout the app?

```
  ## Upload Datafrma
  uploadDataframe <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$uploadData_uploadFile)) return (NULL)
    df <- read_csv(input$uploadData_uploadFile$datapath)

    return(df)
  }) 

  ## Display Table
  output$uploadData_df <- renderDataTable({
    uploadDataframe()
  })

  ## Show Summary of Table
  output$uploadData_Summary <- renderText({
    summary(uploadDataframe())
  })

  ## Plot
  output$uploadData_Summary <- renderText({
    ggplot(uploadDataframe()) + ...
  })
```

In the above example, we're calling `uploadDataFrame()` reactive function for each task that we want to perform which in turn reads the data from the file-system again and again. If the dataset is big, there'd be a lot of time wastage to read it again and again. Is there a way where we can just read the data once and use it everywhere? The data should be isolated for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shiny already handles this efficiently. The reactive `uploadDataFrame()` is evaluated only once whenever it is ***needed*** the first time and then reevaluated only when the input it depends on are invalidated (in this case if `input$uploadData_uploadFile` changes). So in this case, `read_csv` is called only once per input file and not every time you call the reactive.

Further more Shiny will evaluate/reevaluate any reactive lazily i.e. only when the reactive is ***needed***. So if you never actually use `uploadDataFrame()` in your code the `read_csv` will never be called even if you upload a file.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you could store the data in reactiveValues and upload the data only if the data.frame does not exist yet. In the following example, you will see that rendering the table takes 2 seconds only at the beginning.

```
    library(shiny)

    # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
    ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("DF"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("up","Upload")
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    exist <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)

    uploadDataframe <- eventReactive(input$up,{

        if (is.null(exist$df)) {

        Sys.sleep(2)

        data <- data.frame("a"=c(1,1),"b"=c(2,2))

        exist$df <- data

        } else {

        data <- exist$df    

        }

        data


    }) 


    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        uploadDataframe()
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can just replace the actionButton and the sample df with your uploaded data.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered using serviceWorkers for the task of reading the data  data once and using it everywhere. Go to MDN(Mozilla Developer Network). I think there's an article on service workers and the kind of repetitive tasks you described here.